# Twitter Stories Converting to AMP

Tags: twitter, google-analytics, amp-html

I have an enquiry on Twitter story converting to amp article.
Currently I have an article that can be viewed as normal view(desktop) and amp article(mobile). But when we input the URL link into Twitter Stories, Twitter will convert into amp article.

We have also incorporated Google Analytics in our website and thus if my title of the amp article is : GAMP - Title of Article, my statisics for those articles viewed from Twitter will be the same as my mobile.

Google Analytics : 
AMP article: 
Title : GAMP - Title of Article 
Medium:Organic 
Source:Google

Twitter: 
Title : GAMP - Title of Article 
Medium:Social 
Source:Twitter

Is it doable that the title of the article will be “Twitter - Title of Article” and not “GAMP - TItle of Article” in Google Analytics if is viewed from Twitter?

Appreciate any help. Thank You.

Comment: You could check this [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/publisher-tools/amp/overview.html) to change the title of the article on twitter using AMP.

Comment: HI Jess, the article going to Twitter and Google AMP are both the same so I am not able to differentiate the title.Is there any way to change the Title to be different when a viewer view the same article from Google and Twitter Stories. Is this doable?

Comment: Any idea on the above?